# Blocked: How to give additional padding to a button , ONLY if it has an external icon?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I am trying to give some padding to a button IF the button has an external icon in it. If there is an external icon, I want to give the button the `padding-right: 30px` [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6mdC.png).  However, If there is no external icon, then the button shouldn't get the 30px padding. Currently, I am having the issue of the 30px padding-right still showing up even if there no external icon. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WZtE.png)

Is there a way to switch the CSS depending on the external icon being present or not?

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  height: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #FFFFF;
  color: #515151;
  margin-top: 19px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  border: solid #FFFFFF 1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="......." title="Hello World" class="btn btn-default" role="button" target="_blank">
    Button Title
    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-external-link fa-w-16 pull-right" title="external link icon" aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-u1BaVqD2mZ2F" data-prefix="far" data-icon="external-link" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
        <title id="svg-inline--fa-title-u1BaVqD2mZ2F">external link icon</title>
    </svg>
    <!-- <i class="far fa-external-link pull-right" title="external link icon"></i> -->
</a>
```

Comment: Just a note: **The `background: #FFFFF;` should be `background: #FFFFFF;`.** Hex value of `white` has either `3` or `6`, `f`'s in it.

Comment: You basically want [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), but that has no real browser support yet.

Answer (score 0):

well it can be achieved by using `:has()` pseudo selector.

```
.btn:has(svg) {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

but `:has()` is currently not supported by browsers so I would recommend to use it as of now.

but here's a work-around...

maybe you can add padding or marign to the icon itself.

```
.btn > svg { margin-right: 30px }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use js for this, you're not able to do it with pure css
you can do that by .style property and whenever you wanted that button to have a padding-right of 30 px you should add some js for example in this case i want to add this padding during the click event :

```
const btn=document.queryselector(".btn");
btn.addeventlistiner("click",()=>{
btn.style.padding="30px"
})
```

You can of course add it during another event it was just an example.

Comment: Not sure why you have added a click event? OP does not state anywhere that the padding has to be added with a click event.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).